# Landing page for Desktop application

Tags: desktop-application, landing-page, first-impression

My Windows application opens with a grey screen and a search view in the sidebar. The purpose of the app is to search cases on a server, edit them and save them. Altough it migh be sufficient for starting work, I thought that showing just a blank void is a bad (especially first-time) experience.

I was wondering: what better ways are there to welcome my users and help them get into the application? What good landing pages are out there that aren't just pointless "Welcome" screens and actually serve a meaningful purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Add a start form, a place search box, and a list of previous searches made by the current user (under the search box). I think that many people do the same searches every day.

A summary statistics page would be a nice solution. It’s very interesting to know some numbers and performance stats.

Answer (score 2):

I think not just for the first time. For *every time* you can have a wallpaper or big bold text giving a hint of the application.

**1. With wallpaper**

Example.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frRcSf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

But the [Google](http://www.google.com) search page is the best example.

**2. Without Wallpaper**

In case you don't want Wallpaper:

Try this with a ***tool-tip*** popping each time the application is opened.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpAg3X.png)</sup>

**EDIT:** 
Like another user has replied, Summary statistics is also a good idea. Though initially all statistics will be zero. Yet it requires additional work to code those or make use of another API.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to stats, a list of recently worked on items or previous searches can fill the void and provide a useful set of links to assist users in (re)finding items.